# how to add link/image shortcuts to Plone's TinyMCE content browser?

Tags: tinymce, plone, plone-4.x

Under PloneControlCenter => TinyMCE =>Content Browser, I would like to add a certain */Pictures* folder I have at my plone site. How can I do this, I am only allowed to chose from "start" and "current folder"? The list of shortcuts is empty for link and image shortcuts, see the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in Products.TinyMCE 1.3 you can add libraries yourself by providing a utility that implements ITinyMCEShortcut.

see https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/blob/1.3.5/Products/TinyMCE/configure.zcml for the registration and 
https://github.com/plone/Products.TinyMCE/blob/1.3.5/Products/TinyMCE/shortcut.py
for the implementation of the currently available shortcuts